# Creating a new entity with a field of type optionset

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have an html form which does a post to an aspx page which uses the SOAP web services to connect to CRM. The code behind the page creates an entity in the CRM. I am using the IOrganizationService in my code behind.

The code looks like

```cs
IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;                       
Entity lead = new Entity("lead");
string fieldValue = string.Empty;

foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if (key.Equals(SubmitKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false &&
        key.Equals(CRMHostKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false &&
        key.Equals(redirectErrorURLKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false && 
        key.Equals(redirectSuccessURLKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form[key]))
        {
            fieldValue = Request.Form[key].Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            fieldValue = string.Empty;
        }

        if (key.Equals("new_contacttypechoices", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            lead[key] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Email", 100000000);
            //OptionMetadata objOM = GetOptionMetadata("lead", "new_contacttypechoices", fieldValue, service);
            //lead[key] = objOM;
            //lead[key] = 100000000; //Incorrect attribute value type System.Int32
            //lead[key] = fieldValue; //Incorrect attribute value type System.String
        }
        else
        {
            lead[key] = fieldValue;
        }
    }
    newLeadID = service.Create(lead);
}
```

Screenshot of the field [image]

I get an error when I try

```cs
lead[key] = fieldValue
```

I get an error when I try

```cs
lead[key] = 100000000
```

I get an error when I try

```cs
lead[key] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Email", 100000000);
```

I get an error when I get the OptionMetaData and set that to the entity. Any ideas on how to create an entity using an optionset?

Thanks

Comment: Oops - my apols, just noticed the inline comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the error you are getting, but if lead is of type `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity`, it could be that you need to either replace an existing value or add a new one.

```cs
if (lead.Attributes.Contains(key))
{
    lead[key] = new OptionSetValue(100000000);        
}
else 
{
    lead.Attributes.Add(key, new OptionSetValue(100000000));        
}
```

Rereading I notice you have put (presumably) the errors in comments. In that case, I suggest the issue is that you need to assign a value of type `OptionSetValue`